# How to run a python script in a terminal upon login?

Tags: debian, terminal, python

I have my `Debian virtual machine` set to automatically login, and I want to make it so that, when the auto-login occurs, a terminal will open and run the command

```
python /home/pymodbus/examples/common/synchronous_client.py
```

The output from the python script occurs within the terminal, which is why I would like to open it in the first place. I have already done a lot of research, and have tried many things, including put this command in the **`/etc/rc.local`** file, but this did not appear to do anything.

Additionally, I tried this

```
gnome-terminal -e "python /home/pymodbus/examples/common/synchronous_client.py"
```

But this did not start the terminal upon login as I thought it would.

Does anyone have some insight into how to accomplish this? I am very new to Linux, and trying to figure out which packages and tools I need has been a very confusing experience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to figure out how to do this, and I wanted to share my findings here. Here're the steps I took:

1. To get the command to run at startup, I edited the `.bashrc` file in `/home/etc/` and put my command at the very end, after all the prewritten code (`sudo python /home/usr/pymodbus/examples/common/synchronous_client.py`). **Make sure you have sudo in your command.**
2. To get the terminal to launch at startup, I created a desktop file in `~/.config/autostart` (if you don't have the autostart folder, you can just create one).
3. In the autostart folder, I created a `.desktop` file called `gnome-terminal.desktop` and populated it as follows:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Type=Application
   Exec=gnome-terminal
   Hidden=false
   NoDisplay=false
   X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
   Name[en_NG]=Terminal
   Name=Terminal
   Comment[en_NG]=Start Terminal On Startup
   Comment=Start Terminal On Startup
   ```
4. Finally, to bypass the need to type the `sudo` password when I wanted to run the script, I ran the command `sudo visudo` and put the following line at the very end of the file:

   ```
   <username> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
   ```

I hope this helps anyone that might be attempting to do something similar to me!

Comment: Nice work - welcome to superuser!

Answer (score 0):

Look into using cron as a startup mechanism. At the bottom of the cron entry list add `@reboot python /home/pymodbus/examples/common/synchronous_client.py &` (don't forget the &) You can set a script to run on computer startup - Don't forget to chmod +x the script in question - This enables the system to execute the script.

cron is accessed by typing `sudo crontab -e`

Comment: I just tried this, but it doesn't appear to do anything. Is there a way to get the terminal to open and run the command? The output from the command is displayed in the terminal, and I just want to make sure that it's doing what it's supposed to.

Comment: If you remove the & symbol it should hold the terminal window open when it starts. Additionally type 'dmesg | grep cron' for any error messages regarding cron in the logs.

Getting an app to run at startup is a vey challenging experience as it changes far too often. Let me know how it goes and we can also try other methods.

Comment: Hey, so I tried removing the '&' from the command and rebooting, but nothing seems to have changed. Additionally, running the command 'sudo dmesg | grep cron' results in no output. Am I doing something wrong? I literally just put the command I wanted on line 24 of the cron file you specified.

Comment: Let me try the same as you here - The linux startup thing has been a bugbear of mine for years .... will let you know

Comment: Okay thank you! I'm looking forward to seeing what you find!

Comment: Thank for for your help in guiding my research :) I hope my solution helps you too!